# Search and Reload TableView Records with new data

Tags: xcode, search, core-data, uitableview

I am developing IOS app, using Xcode 8 and swift 3. My app has list of items shown in tableView I want to search for a particular item by Date "using datePicker". these items are stored in the Core database.

here is my code. it searches well but I have trouble in displaying the search data.

```
@IBAction func searchButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    if(dateText.text != nil){
        let request = NSFetchRequest <NSFetchRequestResult> (entityName : "Expense_Table")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
      request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "expenseDate = %@", dateText.text!)

     do {
            let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! customeCell

            let result = try self.context.fetch(request)

            if (result.count > 0) {
                for results in result as! [NSManagedObject]
                {
                first = results.value(forKey : "exoenseName") as! String
                last  = results.value(forKey : "expenseAmount") as! Double
                second = results.value(forKey: "expenseDate") as! String
                    //print the data in the Output section of Xcode
                    print (second)
                    print (String (last))
                    print (first)

                    // save data in the cell of the tableView
                    cell.dateText.text = second
                    cell.amounttext.text = String (last)
                    cell.nameText.text = first

                    tableView.addSubview(cell)// this method print result over the table view data 


                }
                tableView.reloadData()


            }
        }catch{}



        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the model-view-controller pattern.

- Create a **model** on the top level of the class

  ```
  var expenses = [NSManagedObject]()
  ```
- In the `searchButton` method the **controller** loads the data into the model and calls `reloadData`

  ```
  @IBAction func searchButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    if  dateText.text != nil {
      let request = NSFetchRequest <NSFetchRequestResult> (entityName : "Expense_Table")
      request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
      request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "expenseDate = %@", dateText.text!)

      do {
        expenses = try self.context.fetch(request) as! [NSManagedObject]
        tableView.reloadData()
      } catch { print(error) }
    }
  }
  ```
- In cellForRowAtIndexPath the **view** is updated

  ```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)  as! customeCell
    let expense = expenses[indexPath.row]
    let first = expense.value(forKey : "exoenseName") as! String
    let last  = expense.value(forKey : "expenseAmount") as! Double
    let second = expense.value(forKey: "expenseDate") as! String
    // save data in the cell of the tableView
    cell.dateText!.text = second
    cell.amounttext!.text = String(last)!
    cell.nameText!.text = first

    return cell
  }
  ```

Comment: I try your code and it shows me error at (let expense = expenses [indexPath.row]. Also, I have query I used this method "cellForRowAt" to display the whole data in Core database, so how can I use it again to display the search data?

Comment: The error is fatal error: Index out of range and near the code Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Comment: the problem is  in the method numberOfRowsInSection, but I don't know how to fix it, please help me I'm a new developer for IOS app :(

Comment: In `numberOfRowsInSection` return `expenses.count`